# A question about uniformities generated by pseudometrics

Tags: gn.general-topology, uniform-spaces

Suppose that for all $n$ natural numbers, $d_{n}$ is a pseudometric on set $X
$. Define $d=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }a_{n}\frac{d_{n}}{1+d_{n}}$, where $\left(
a_{n}\right) $ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum_{n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
}a_{n}<\infty $.

It is claimed that the uniformity $\mathcal{U}_{d}$ generated by
pseudometric $d$ is the same the uniformity $\mathcal{U}_{P}$ generated by
pseudometrics $P=\left\{ d_{n}:n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
\right\} $, that is $\mathcal{U}_{d}=\mathcal{U}_{P}$.

At page 237 in Topology Book by W. W. Fairchild, C. I. Tulcea,

https://archive.org/details/topology0000fair/page/236/mode/2up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction:
let $\varepsilon>0$ and taken $N$ such that $\sum_{n>N}a_n<\frac12\varepsilon$. Take $\delta>0$ such that $\delta\cdot\sum_{n\le N}a_n<\frac12\varepsilon$. Now if $d_n(x,y)<\delta$ for all $n\le N$ then
$$
d(x,y)< \delta\cdot\sum_{n\le N}a_n+\sum_{n>N}a_n<\varepsilon
$$
(because $d_n(x,y)/(1+d_n(x,y))\le d_n(x,y)$ always).

For the second direction: you have $a_n\cdot d_n(x,y)/(1+d_n(x,y))\le d(x,y)$. Then from $d(x,y)\le\frac12a_n$ you get $d_n(x,y)/(1+d_n(x,y))\le\frac12$ and then $d_n(x,y)\le1$. And from this you get $\frac12d_n(x,y)\le d_n(x,y)/(1+d_n(x,y))$. In summary: if $d(x,y)\le\frac12a_n$ then $\frac{a_n}2d_n(x,y)\le d(x,y)$, so you have an explicit formula for $\delta$ in terms of $\varepsilon$ to show uniform continuity of the identity.

Comment: For the second direction, I understand that

Given $\varepsilon >0$ ve $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Let's choose $\delta \leq \min \left\{ \frac{a_{n}}{2},\frac{a_{n}\varepsilon }{2}\right\} $.

Comment: We have $\frac{a_{n}d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }{1+d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }\leq
d\left( x,y\right) $. Suppose that $d\left( x,y\right) <\delta $. Then $\frac{a_{n}d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }{1+d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }<\delta \leq 
\frac{a_{n}}{2}\Rightarrow \frac{d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }{1+d_{n}\left(
x,y\right) }<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: $\Rightarrow d_{n}\left( x,y\right) <1\Rightarrow 1+d_{n}\left( x,y\right) <2
$. From this, we get $\frac{d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }{2}<\frac{d_{n}\left(
x,y\right) }{1+d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }$. Hence $\Rightarrow \frac{
a_{n}d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }{2}<\frac{a_{n}d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }{
1+d_{n}\left( x,y\right) }\leq d\left( x,y\right) $

Comment: $\Rightarrow d_{n}\left( x,y\right) <\frac{2}{a_{n}}d\left( x,y\right) <
\frac{2}{a_{n}}\delta \leq \frac{2}{a_{n}}\cdot \frac{a_{n}\varepsilon }{2}
=\varepsilon\Rightarrow d_{n}\left( x,y\right) <\varepsilon $.

Comment: Consequently, $d\left( x,y\right) <\delta \Rightarrow d_{n}\left( x,y\right)
<\varepsilon $.

Comment: Yes. (It would be wiser to have these in just one comment; hit shift+enter to go to a new line *inside* a comment.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that thank you